# How to include a file only on dashboard widgets page?

Tags: theme-development, widgets, admin, wp-enqueue-style

I want to add some styles to the widgets input fields. Therefore I want to include a style.css file only on the `wp-admin/widgets.php` page.

How can I detect the above page and include file there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code. Asuming that the css file `style.css` is inside the css folder of your theme:

```
function wpse_126614_enque( $hook ) {
    if ( 'widgets.php' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }
    $template_url = get_template_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'admin-style-widget', $template_url . '/css/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_126614_enque' );
```